# Visual Studio: Possible to change the keyboard shortcut in for switching the overload on the Parameter Info popup?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard

In Visual Studio 2013, is it possible to change the keyboard shortcut for switching the overload on the Parameter Info popup to something other than up and down arrows?

For example, when you type:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(
```

A little box pops up telling you about overload 1 of 3 for that method. Pressing the down arrow will go to 2 of 3 etc. As a point of fact, the up and down arrows already serve the nifty function of moving the cursor. When that box is visible, you have to hit escape to get the up and down arrows back to their normal behavior.

My question is this, can you change the Parameter Info box up + down keyboard shortcuts to be something else, like control up or down?

I did notice that the left and right arrow keys might be a bit better than the escape key, but I'd still prefer to remap the up and down behavior so they can make the box go away.

I realized how much time (and hand movement) I spend hitting the escape and figured it'd be worth asking. I do not think this falls under the category of the keyboard shortcuts that you can remap from the Options screen.

Many thanks!